# Why don't we say "this is a Succah our forefathers used in Exodus"

Tags: passover-seder-hagada, sukkah, yetziat-mitzrayim

On the Seder Night, we say הא לחמא עניא - this is the bread our ancestors ate in Egypt.

The Torah says we should sit in Succos as G-d made Succos in Exodus ([Lev 23.43](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Leviticus.23.43?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0)).

> לְמַעַן יֵדְעוּ דֹרֹתֵיכֶם כִּי בַסֻּכּוֹת הוֹשַׁבְתִּי אֶת־בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל בְּהוֹצִיאִי אוֹתָם מֵאֶרֶץ מִצְרָיִם אֲנִי ה"א׃
>
> in order that future generations may know that I made the Israelite people live in booths when I brought them out of the land of Egypt, I the LORD your God.

Why don't we remind that fact on Succos, sitting in Succah?

Comment: והגדת לבנך: בשעה שיש מצות ומרורים מונחים לפניך

Comment: @DoubleAA Interesting, you're saying it's a part of the Aggadah? It seems to preface it IMHO. כל דכפין is just a call. We do invite אושפיזין into Succah also.

Comment: There's no mitzva of sippur on sukkot or the last 6.5 days of pesach. It might be nice to help people remember what they're supposed to, but I don't know why you'd expect a formal liturgy.